# Can macro variadic parameters being expanded?

Tags: c++, macros

I have a lot of custom attributes (by using clang annotate, if you ask), and it is annoying to write

```
__attribute(a)__ __attribute(b)__ __attribute(c)__ int i;
```

can I design a macro,for example `MyAttr(...)`,
if I use `MyAttr(a,b,c)`, it will expand to `__attribute(a)__ __attribute(b)__ __attribute(c)__`?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with boost.preprocessor, something like this:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define ATTRIBUTE(r, _, elem) __attribute__((elem))

#define ATTRIBUTES(seq) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(ATTRIBUTE, _, seq)

ATTRIBUTES((a)(b)(c)(d)) // expands to __attribute__((a)) __attribute__((b)) __attribute__((c)) __attribute__((d))
```